# Iterate through values of a HASH and convert to comma separated strings

Tags: perl, data-structures, hash

I want to iterate through the values of a big hash, and if any of the values of that hash are keys, I want to convert it into a comma separated list which can be parsed in 'query_form'.

Right now from the data below I have:

name=Bob&surname=Whitbread&customerErrors=HASH(Xa456) (for example)

Here's what I have so far:

```
    sub convertArgsToQueryString {
    my $class = shift;
    my $args = shift;

    return unless ($args && ref($args) eq 'HASH');

    foreach my $key (values %$args) {
        if (ref($key) eq 'HASH') {
            # change to a comma separated list
        }
    }

    my $dummyURL = URI->new('', 'http');
    $dummyURL->query_form(%$args);

    return $dummyURL->query;
  }
```

Data:

```
my $data = {
    'name' => 'Bob',
    'surname' => 'Whitbread',
    'customerErrors' => {
        'error1' => 'paymentError',
        'error2' => 'addressError'
    },
};
```

Query Form:

name=Bob&surname=Whitbread&customerErrors=paymentError,addressError

Comment: I dont understand the problem? Do you have expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you want

```
print join ",", values %{$data->{customerErrors}},"\n";
```

Although I would suggest, rather than `error1` as hash keys, you'd be better off with an array:

```
my $data = {
   'name'           => 'Bob',
   'surname'        => 'Whitbread',
   'customerErrors' => [ 'paymentError', 'addressError' ],
};
```

Scaling that out to be generic, you will find the `ref` function to be helpful:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$data ) { 
    print "$key is a ", ref $data->{$key},"\n";
    if ( ref $data->{$key} eq 'HASH' ) { 
       print join ",", values %{$data->{$key}};
    }
    else { 
        print $data -> {$key},"\n"; 
    }
}
```

Or tersely:

```
print join "\&", map {  #join iterated on &
   join "=", $_,   #join paired values on =
     ref $data->{$_} eq 'HASH'   #ternary to check reference type
     ? values %{ $data->{$_} }   #extract values if HASH
     : $data->{$_}               #extract just value if not. 
} keys %$data;  #iterate keys of data
```

Which gives as output:

```
name=Bob&customerErrors=addressError=paymentError&surname=Whitbread
```